# jQuery: if checkbox is checked remove part of form

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a form with function when someone checks input or inputs with classes **.badCheckbox, .badCheckbox2, .badCheckbox3** *fieldset* with an id ***goodField*** from the form will be removed and *fieldset* with id ***badField*** will be appended. If someone unchecks checkbox with mentioned classes the removed *fieldset* with id ***goodField*** of the form will be shown again and appended *fieldset* ***badField*** will be removed. I tried something like that but not working. Also, I tried it with display: block and none and again not working.

**My jQuery:**

```
$('.badCheckbox, .badCheckbox2, .badCheckbox3').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('#badField').appendTo( "form" );
        $('#goodField').detach();
    } else {
        $('#badField').detach()
        $('#goodField').appendTo( "form" );
    }
});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input class="badCheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
    <input class="badCheckbox2" type="checkbox"/>
    <input class="badCheckbox3" type="checkbox"/>
    <fieldset id="badField">
        <p>Sorry:(</p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="goodField">
        <p>Nice!!!</p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Can't you simply have both good and bad element in the form and ``.hide()`` or ``.show()`` it based on checkbox checked? It's much better for performance than editing DOM and simpler to write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? ↓↓

```js
$('.badCheckbox').change(function() {
  let checked = 0;
  $('.badCheckbox').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      checked += 1;
    }
  });
  if (checked != 0) {
    $('#badField').show();
    $('#goodField').hide();
  } else {
    $('#badField').hide();
    $('#goodField').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form> 
  <input class="badCheckbox" type="checkbox" /> 
  <input class="badCheckbox" type="checkbox" /> 
  <input class="badCheckbox" type="checkbox" />
  <fieldset id="badField" style="display:none;">
    <p>Sorry:(</p> <button type="submit">Submit</button> </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="goodField">
    <p>Nice!!!</p> <button type="submit">Submit</button> </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? 
You need only one class for this badCheckbox, as they all do the same if I understand you right. And display block none works just fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.badCheckbox').change(function () {
   if (this.checked) {
             $("#goodField").css("display", "none");
             $("#badField").css("display", "block");
         }
         else {
             $("#goodField").css("display", "block");
             $("#badField").css("display", "none");
         }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input class="badCheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
    <input class="badCheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
    <input class="badCheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
    <fieldset id="badField" style="display:none">
        <p>Sorry:(</p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="goodField" style="display:block">
        <p>Nice!!!</p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: when all checkboxes are checked and one I uncheck goodField will be shown, the first answer is what I wanted but thanks for the time!!!